# Merging table by group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with human genes. I want to check all possible combination of alleles. So my df:

```
Human     Gene    AllelA    AllelB
1         gene1      C        C
1         gene2      A        T
1         gene3      G        G
1         gene4      T        A
2         gene1      C        C
2         gene2      G        G
3         gene4      C        C
4         gene1      A        T
5         gene4      C        C
```

And now I need to check all ways so I think the better way will be pivot thah table to (first I merging gene to one column Allele1Allele2, so in Gene1 for Human1 it will be one column contains: CC):

```
humanNumber     Gene1    Gene2    Gene3   Gene4
```

And then just do some magic with merge columns. But now I have a problem with pivot it. When I tried I got error telling that my index is not unique (indeed it isn't), so I tried to group by the table, but it's completly unclear for my to pivot it.

I know - and I did - I can do that by loop in pure python, but first: it's long (80k people x 2|3|4 genes) and second: I think pandas can do that better. I just can't applay the pivot function. Tried in different way, using different indexes... but still problems.

Expectation:

```
  humanNumber     Gene1    Gene2    Gene3   Gene4  
       1            CC       AT       GG      TA
etc.
```

Can someone help me do that right?

P.S. whole dataframe is filled by strings

Comment: Is `Gene4` typo `TA`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem are duplicates by `Human` and `Gene`, you can check them:

```
print (df)
   Human   Gene AllelA AllelB
0      1  gene1      C      C <- added dupe row for test
1      1  gene1      C      C
2      1  gene2      A      T
3      1  gene3      G      G
4      1  gene4      T      A
5      2  gene1      C      C
6      2  gene2      G      G
7      3  gene4      C      C
8      4  gene1      A      T
9      5  gene4      C      C

print (df[df.duplicated(['Human','Gene'], keep=False)])
   Human   Gene AllelA AllelB
0      1  gene1      C      C
1      1  gene1      C      C
```

If possible, you can remove them by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = (df.drop_duplicates(['Human','Gene'])
        .assign(Alle = lambda x: df['AllelA'] + df['AllelB'])
        .pivot('Human','Gene','Alle'))
print (df)
Gene  gene1 gene2 gene3 gene4
Human                        
1        CC    AT    GG    TA
2        CC    GG   NaN   NaN
3       NaN   NaN   NaN    CC
4        AT   NaN   NaN   NaN
5       NaN   NaN   NaN    CC
```

Comment: Ou! I totally forgot about drop duplicates... and even It says it's problem with duplicates, I was thinking It's because I have few same humans in index... 
All wokrks excellent now. Thank U very much!